# React Native Agora can't get a list of streams at my project channel

Tags: react-native, live-streaming, agora.io

I realized that i can get the stream in a channel in AGORA api by using RtcLocalView, the problem is, I have no control over the content, what I want is to get a list of current streams in my project channel, I've already sent them an email asking for instructions if that is possible, but nothing so far.

So my questions is, is it possible to get a list of streams using react-native-agora?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want access to the stream data to perform some processing, in that case you can use the raw data plugin for react-native-agora: https://github.com/AgoraLibrary/react-native-agora-rawdata